# multiple records in one NDEF message on one NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

How many records can NDEF message encapsulate?
(for different NFC tag types - 1,2,3,4?)

And in general ...do I understand it right?  :

I can have one NFC message, which is basically an array(of what capacity?) of NFC records.
Each NFC record has its own MIME-type, which facilitates application recognition

```
<data android:mimeType="specific application MIME-type goes here"/>
```

so I can launch different applications even if I use just one tag.

Comment: ie on one tap i can load 2+ applications easily or perform 2+ actions?

Answer (score 0):

The number of records in a **NDEF message** is limited by the memory of the **tag**. There is no difference in that for the various **tag types**.

When you tap a **tag** with the phone, the whole **NDEF message** is delivered to one app. Anything else you would need to program yourself after you received the message.